# encode and decode images in java

Tags: java, jms, decode, encode

how do you encode and decode images in java?

I have this following scenario, I want to encode an image for example(abc.gif) in any format (bytes, base64). Then Send it over a SOAP message and decode the image and save the image in a folder on another computer.

I am exposing this as a web service. I am using TIBCO designer to invoke this web service of encoding of images.

Any way to do the java encoding of images?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [`Image`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) from an array of bytes with [`Toolkit.createImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage%28byte%5b%5d%29). To encode an image you could use an [`ImageWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html). In general, the complete [`javax.imageio`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) package can probably help you a lot.

Comment: i cant seem to find any free open source codes for this, as I am really unsure how to use this approach to encode the image.

Comment: This might be a good opportunity to hone your javadoc skills. For decoding, search the documentation for functions that accept a `byte[]` or `InputStream` as parameter and return an `Image`. When encoding, search for the other way around. For base64 encoding you either roll your own or use some third-party library (Apache probably has some, and Google will still know more), that’s basically all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for libraries to do Base64 or similar encoding/decoding, then I would say [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/). At least that's what I've used in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just transfer the bytes of the image file plus additional information like filename etc. Then you just write the bytes to a new file and you're done. It's more like general file streaming, but you might also put some information on the image into the header (where the filename is).